# I can't add allprojects in my build.gradle when I use the imageSlider library

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

[This is my code, I want to use the ImageSlider but lib but when I add the allreposity at mu gradle it provides an error **' Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSbMe.png)

I try using the imageSlider Lib from GitHub but when I was just at the dependency the library can't use. so I try to search and the solution is to add the maven to the build.gradle but the problem is when I add the all project block it provides an error:

Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserCodeException: Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'

Comment: There are two `build.gradle` files. One inside the project dir and one inside the app dir. You need to add this code into the project level `build.gradle` file. Not the app level one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firs of all you are adding the library to module level "build.gradle" you need to add it to project level "build.gradle" in old android studio versions.

if you are using latest Android studio version then you need to add maven to setting.gradle file not in build.gradle below is the example to add dependency to setting.gradle file

```
//here you have to add.
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
}
```